# SKPhysicsBody rises CPU usage

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I'm just about done with a game that is based on physics. I noticed that Xcode is saying the energy impact is "Very High" which makes sense because the CPU usage is about 21-26%. (I'm using an iPhone 6 in the release configuration, not the simulator) I figured out where the problem seems to be which is the SKPhysicsBody of each node. When I comment out the initialization of the physics body the cpu usage drops to 4-7% and energy impact reads "Low". Can someone give me some insight on what to do?

```
class Item:SKSpriteNode {

var id:[Int]

init(type: String, ID: [Int]) {
    self.id = ID
    var newTexture = SKTexture(imageNamed: type)
    super.init(texture: newTexture, color: UIColor(), size: newTexture.size())
    self.name = type
    setPhysicsBody()
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) { fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented") }


func setPhysicsBody() {
    physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: 3)
    physicsBody?.isDynamic = false
    physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = bitMask.obstacleCategory
    physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = bitMask.ballCategory
    physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = bitMask.ballCategory
    physicsBody?.restitution = 0.05
    physicsBody?.friction = 0.1
}

}
```

Comment: This is pretty much expected behavior. Just about any game that utilizes physics bodies (which is practically every game) will tax the system. Think back to physics and all the complex integrals being calculated in microseconds. Really, I think you're stressing over something that's totally normal.

Comment: Are you rapidly creating new nodes that could be reused? Otherwise this is expected behaviour, the CPU has to calculate the physics of each node every frame.

Comment: @Pierce Oh ok, not generating a lot of nodes just about 5 or 6. But what you both said about the calculations make sense. Thank you

Comment: @LeonStorey Thank you

Comment: With only 5 or 6 nodes, that 25% CPU use seems a bit high. I have done some experiments with 100's of nodes, each with physics bodies and seen that kind of number, whilst they fly around the screen interacting with each other. But not with 5 or 6. How complex are the physic's bodies, and how are you creating them? Are you using fields?

Comment: @Confused Most of the physics bodies are being created the same way as shown in my code except some are initialized using the texture of the spritenode. However I changed all of them to circles to see if that was the problem, but it wasn't. No fieldnodes though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can help ease the CPU load by setting the `SKPhysicsBody`'s `contactTestBitMask` and `collisionBitMask`. By default, the CPU is keeping track of each physics body and its relation to *all* other physics bodies. By setting the `contactTestBitMask` and `collisionBitMask`, you can tell the CPU to only worry about the objects you need the physics body to interact with.